# how best to index columns in a table with dynamic relationships to other tables?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Some of our tables have dynamic relationships to other tables.

for example - we have an address table that stores all addresses, in it are two 'linking' fields- entity_id and entity_key_id, that are used to link the addresses to other tables.

For instance 'member' might be entity_id 1 and 'organization' might be entity id 2, so if we are storing a member address the row would have entity_id = 1 and entity_key_id = mem_id (the pk of the mem table), but if we are storing an organization address, the row would have entity_id = 2 and entity_key_id would store the pk of the org table).

how best would I index this? should I have 2 indexes- one for the entity_id and one for the entity_key_id? or would it be better to include both columns in a single index, and if so, in what order?

The db is SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Is this just those two possibilities or is this an EAV type of thing?

Comment: Filtered Indexes?  But you probably don't want to create 50 filtered indexes if you have 50  entityID's.  I agree @SeanLange it sounds very EAV

Comment: Hard to say really...the OP seems to have gone AWOL shortly after asking a question.

Comment: Yes it is EOV (I think - didnt know the name for it). Sorry for going AWOL - its my first stack exchange question and all the response were going to my junk mail folder. the two possibilities were examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on queries you are going to run against this database. You can use Tuning Adviser  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575(v=sql.100).aspx), it will help.

But generally you should have index with columns in the order you use for predicate (`WHERE`) and columns you select. Here are some examples.

`SELECT ... from table1 where table1.column1=.. and table1.column2=..`.

Here you should have `column1, column2` index, so DB will be able to first find all `column1` and then all `column2` directly from index. You may also have `column1` index, but in this case DB will first read `column1` from index, and then go to table itself, which is slower.

But if your have `column2, column42, column1` index it will not be used since DB can't follow your `WHERE` condition.

It is also good to have column in index.

Running `select column1 from table1 where column2=...` with index `column2, column1` will give DB ability to read both columns from index and not even touch table! It is fast. But if you change order in this index, it will not be used becase DB needs `column2` (according to `WHERE`).

You should **always** profiler to obtain execution plan: use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.100).aspx : not only it helps you to find bottlenecks but also teaches you how DB optimizer uses indecies.

Comment: thanks - I had read up in the microsoft best practices article but was having issues with the order of the index.

"Running select column1 from table1 where column2=... with index column2, column1 will give DB ability to read both columns from index and not even touch table! It is fast. But if you change order in this index, it will not be used becase DB needs column2 (according to WHERE)."

This is exactly what I was looking for - i have added the index 'entity_id, entity_key_id'

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to have two distinct keys `mem_key_id` and  `org_key_id`. This not only allows you to create an index on each of them but also to declare proper foreign key constraints.

One of the two keys would always be null.

Comment: the two were just examples - any number of entities could be added at a later date. i personally would be using join tables but am working under the restrictions of a model I did not design.